# Get range of columns in empty sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

Consider the google sheet is empty and the amount of columns are unknown:

[image]

How do I find out the range of this EMPTY sheet?

I tried:

```
$this->service->spreadsheets_values->get($sheetId, $sheetName)
```

But it just returns an empty range.  Only when I add any data will it show me the range, but I need to know this in advance before I add data.

Answer (score 1):

While I will be refactoring this, I just wanted to say that I did figure this out with the following code:

```
$raw = $this->service->spreadsheets_values->get($sheetId, $sheetName)->getRange();

            $split = explode('!', $raw);

            $range = explode(':', $split[1]);

            $letters = [];

            $letter = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $range[0]);

            while ($letter) {

                $letters[] = $letter++;

                if ($letter == preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $range[1])){
                    break;
                }

                if (sizeof($letters) > 1000)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return $letters;
```